# Why is my project unloaded after being successfully converted?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, resharper

In order to use the latest version of resharper on the much-maligend (by me) project I'm currently maintaining, I copied all the source to a separate folder and opened the project in VS 2010.

It converted successfully, so said the conversion report (after informing me it seemed to be under version control but would be unbound since it was missing needed info for that, which I accepted). Yet, although the conversion was nominally successful, in the Solution explorer, beneath the project name, it says "Project Unloaded"

Now for the nitty-gritty: The project has two related solutions, a "regular" (.exe) and a library (.dll) project; they both display in Solution Explorer, but both say "Project Unloaded."

Now for the strange part: When I realized that I had not even copied over the files from the .dll project, I started over and created two separate folders for them (as they have in the development setup), and copied each one's file into each folder.

But now, when I attempt to open the .exe project (the one which had previously claimed it had been converted successfully) from this new location, by selecting File | Open Project and selecting the *.sln file, I get, "*\.csdproj' cannot be opened because its project type (.csdproj) is not supported by this version of the application.
To open it, please use a version that supports this type of project.*

The dev environment is VS2003 in a XP Mode virtual machine; I'm trying to open the projects now in VS2010 in Windows 7.

Is there a way I can get this project to open and compile in VS2010, so that I can resharperize it (and carry over some of those fixes, albeit manually, one at a time) to the "real live" version of the project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best way would be to create a new project in Visual Studio 2010, like you've done. That will create the project folder and any necessary settings.

Next, copy files from your old project to this new folder. As you copy a file into the new folder, also "Drag-N-Drop" that file into your Visual Studio Solution.

The Visual Studio conversion wizard is good from going from the last version to the next version up, but going from VS2003 to VS2010 could be too big of a jump for it.

If I had to guess, this conversion is bombing because your old project targets the .NET Framework 1.0 and VS2010 doesn't do 1.0.

You will likely have to rebuild your project and fix numerous little bugs due to changes in the Framework, but none should be major.

Comment: That was a good idea, but there are just too many differences over the years. At present I have 804 errors, and I'm afraid all the changes it would take to get it to compile would pretty much negate the benefit I would get, as it would be a fundamentally different project by that time, and the resharperizing I would be able to do would oftentimes not even apply to the old project. Still, I will mark this as the answer because it was a good theory.